# How add multiple values in Text Qualifer

Tags: ssis

I want to remove double quotes and last record in Flat File using Text Qualifier.

[image]

I tried this method for removing double quotes and last row. It's not working .

How to give both values in Text qualifier field.

Comment: what is required ? your question isnt clear !!

Comment: I have to remove in my text file double quotes symbol and last row of the file.

Comment: have you tried anything that dint work ? or could you post some examples with required output ?

Comment: I tried but no use. 
Eg., 

"H"|"NAME"|"ADDRESS"
"D"|"ASIF"|"CHI"
"T"|"Total : 1 Record"


Expected:

H|NAME|ADDRESS
D|ASIF|CHI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly you just want to remove some quotes from your strings. You can do this with a derived column transformation and the [REPLACE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141196.aspx) method.

[image]

Comment: This answer will implement only up to 10 to 20 columns. If more than 1000 columns  of 20 GB data, it will take more time for validation.